# jquery invoked class disappear after reload

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css

I was searching a way to invoke a class when a **li** is clicked and its siblings should get removed from that class, gladly i found the solution which was working exactly same but i realized i have a little different problem as my list is being generated dynamically using php.
**Jquery:**

```
$('.nav').on('click','li', function(){
$(this).addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');
});
```

**CSS**

```
.selected 
{
  background-color:red;
}
```

**List Generated**

```
foreach ($seasons->result() as $key => $value) : ?>
  <li class="dropdown">  
    <a href="<?php echo base_url().'series/names/'. $value->seasons_id_fk .'/'. $value->season_num_id; ?>" ><i class="fa fa-tachometer fa-fw"></i> <?php echo $value->season_num; ?></a></li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Thing is when i'm selecting a **li** item's it has anchor tag as well and i'm sending some more information with previous one and coming back to the same page. In mean time i lost the class i just invoked through jquery.
is there a way through php/jqyery/css to achieve the functionality?

Comment: when you add element dynamically in page you need to bind event(wth .on or .live) again to that element.

Comment: how do we bind it again ? 

Sorry i'm total noob in jquery

Comment: i tried `$('.nav').on('click','li', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
  ` well it keeps the value of class but doesn't send the anchor to the url

Comment: you should use ajax in case of sending request to server side without refreshing page. because you have anchor tag which will redirect you to different page which will loss your current script effect.

Comment: @sandeshjadhav well i'm searching for it without doing ajax thingy, maybe with simple php we can get that